# Pygame window closing instantly with the while run loop

Tags: python

I am watching a tutorial on pygame (made by Tech With Tim) and after following all the stuff with the run variable and the while run function, my window is still closing immediately. I have searched stackoverflow and the pygame forums but they all say stuff similar that doesn't work.

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First game")

BACKGROUND = (255, 255, 255)


def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        WIN.fill(BACKGROUND)
        pygame.display.update()
    
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__name__":
    main()
```

Comment: You haven't called `pygame.init`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if __name__ == "__name__":
```

with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```